# Как удалить читера из таблицы рекордов Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: мою игру взломали на рекорд и он зачёлся в таблице как лучший. Вопрос следующий: как можно удалить фальшивый счёт в таблице рекордов leaderboard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Решение которое помогло мне скрыть читера из таблицы рекордов:

1. Переходим на сервис гугла [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). В правом верхнем углу нажимаем настройки. В выпавшем окошке внизу устанавливаем галочку **Use your own OAuth credentials**. В полях OAuth Client ID и OAuth Client secret вставляем значения идентификатора OAuth 2.0 Вашего приложения. Получить его можно в [Google APIs](https://console.developers.google.com) в разделе Учётные данные. В списке слева надо найти Google Play Game Service. Либо ввести **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games** в поле ниже. На втором шагу получаем токены доступа.

[image: Use your own OAuth credentials]

2. Для начала нам надо узнать playerId игрока, которого Вы хотите скрыть из таблицы рекордов. Для этого отправляем Get запрос:
   `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/LEADERBOARD_ID/scores/PUBLIC?timeSpan=ALL_TIME`

   > LEADERBOARD_ID - Ваш ID таблицы рекордов.

   Подробнее об этом запросе можно узнать [здесь](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list).
3. Выделив нужный playerId, отправляем POST запрос на скрытие игрока:
   `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1management/applications/ID_APPLICATION/players/hidden/PLAYER_ID/`

   > ID_APPLICATION - Номер вашего приложения. Получить его можно в [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/). Как правило это 11 цифр.
   >
   > PLAYER_ID - ID игрока которого надо скрыть.

   Подробнее об этом запросе можно узнать [здесь](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide).
4. Проверяем таблицу рекордов в игре.

Если на 3 этапе у Вас появилась ошибка `There is no linked app associated with this client ID`, то Вам необходимо в [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) связать приложение как Web приложение. Как это сделать можно узнать [здесь](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling).